# JDesktopPane inside JScrollPane resize issue

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jdesktoppane

I have a `JDesktopPane` inside a `JScrollPane`. Inside the `JDesktopPane` there are many `JInternalFrame`s, added programmatically. I would like to have this behavior:

- the `JDesktopPane` should have a fixed size (much larger than the main JFrame size)
- the `JScrollPane` size should vary accordingly to the main JFrame when resized

Basically the same behavior that every image editor has (i.e. Photoshop), but with `JInternalFrame`s in the viewport instead of an image.

At first I thought this behavior would be easy to get, but I can't get it quite right. Surely I'm missing something about layouts or something related...

Here's the related SSCCE

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

class Main extends JFrame {

    JDesktopPane container = new JDesktopPane();

    // New frame with 2 JInternalFrames inside a JDesktopPane inside a JScrollPane
    Main(){
        super("JDesktopPane SS");
        setSize(1280, 720);

        setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());

        container.setBounds(new Rectangle(1920, 1080));

        JScrollPane scrollContainer = new JScrollPane(container, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        setContentPane(scrollContainer);

        container.add(createFrame());
        container.add(createFrame());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            // Create new frame with 2 JInternalFrames inside a JDesktopPane inside a JScrollPane
            JFrame main_frame = new Main();

            main_frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    // Create new InternalFrame with a TextPane
    private JInternalFrame createFrame(){
        JInternalFrame new_frame = new JInternalFrame("Document");
        new_frame.setResizable(true);

        JTextPane txt = new JTextPane();
        txt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
        new_frame.add(txt);

        new_frame.pack();
        new_frame.setVisible(true);

        return new_frame;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JScrollPane viewports don't respect size or bounds but rather **preferred** sizes. So

```
class Main extends JFrame {

    private static final int DT_WIDTH = 1920;
    private static final int DT_HEIGHT = 1080;
    private JDesktopPane container = new JDesktopPane();

    public Main(){
        super("JDesktopPane SS");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1280, 720);

        // setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout()); // ?????

        // container.setBounds(new Rectangle(1920, 1080));
        container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(DT_WIDTH, DT_HEIGHT));
```

Comment: Thanks, now it's working just fine! But one should not use that method, right?

Comment: @Ararararagi: which method, `setPreferredSize(...)`? Perhaps. If you're a purist, then you should override `getPreferredSize()` on either your JDesktopPane or your viewport. But understand that calling `setSize(...)` or `setBounds(...)` is even less recommended.

Comment: @Ararararagi: the most important thing to get out of this though is to understand how the viewport works, and what it uses to size its contained component.

Comment: Then you answered my question! Thanks! Also, if I want to resize JDesktopPane size programmatically during runtime, will I be okay or is it a bad idea?

Comment: @Ararararagi: in that case I would create a class that extends `JDesktopPane`, that implements `Scrollable`, that overrides `getPreferredSize()` as well as the `Scrollable` methods, including and especially the one that returns the preferred viewport size, that has methods for changing the preferred size....

Comment: I see! Thank you!